# Can't change display from none to table with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, I have a code like this.

```
.....

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  display: none;
}

.....

<body onload="readyFunc()">

.....

<script>
function readyFunc() {
   document.getElementById("table").style.display="table";
}
</script>

....
```

What I am trying to do is to show the table only when the document has been loaded. But the table is still not showing.

Comment: Consider using `.display = 'block'` instead?

Comment: How is your HTML? In CSS you are selecting a table tag, in JavaScript you selecting an ID.

Comment: @Azametzin OK, so how do I refer to the table tag in Javascript?

Comment: try `document.querySelector("table").style.display="table";` or add `id="table"` to your table

Comment: does the table have `id="table"`?

Comment: @G-Cyrillus That worked like a Charm :) Maybe you can put that as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may also use [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector)

example:

```js
document.querySelector("table").style.display="table";
```

```css
table {display:none;}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Do you see me ?</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

or give the right id to the table

```js
document.getElementById("table").style.display = "table";
```

```css
table {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td>Do you see me ?</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```